# Assembly uses 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: .net, mono, .net-4.8

I'm in System.Net.Http hell again. In full...

**MyControllerTests.cs.cs(50, 26): [CS1705] Assembly 'My.Api' with identity 'My.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Net.Http' with identity 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'**

I'm trying to get a `.net Framework 4.8` solution building under Mono - I'm very nearly there.

I'm stuck at a late stage with a Test Project for a Web API project where the error above is listed almost 100 times.

I initially had errors in the web API projects which I was able to fix by doing this...

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http"/>
```

One of the 2 test projects for the APIs then started going nuts - probably due to the fact that it has dependencies that are tied to `netstandard2.0`.

The projects in the solution are a real mix - Most of the lower level projects are now SDK style projects and all of them use PackageReference (except for the Web and API projects themselves as they don't support this).

I've tried explicitly adding a reference to the test project but, while the Web API project picks the reference up from the Mono GAC as 4.2.0.0, The test project insists on loading it from the nuget packages directory, which is 4.1.1.3 (Whaaaat?!)

I've tried adding more info to the reference in the API project like this...

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

That made no difference.

I've tried going the other way and explicitly referencing the other version in the eb API project, like this...

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

But then they break again.

I've tried a binding redirect but, as I'm not even at the point of executing code, that was neither use nor ornament.

**UPDATE**
I tried adding a version specific reference to the test project, like this...

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

This changed the error messages on the tes project build from the one above to variations of...

**ContextUtil.cs(12, 175): [CS0433] The type 'HttpRequestMessage' exists in both 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'**

This looks like it can't make up it's mind which version to use even though I have a VERY specific direct reference in the project. If I look at the Assemblies section in the Solution tree it actually shows 2 copies of System.Net.Http - each a different version

Any ideas on what I can try next?

Comment: Today the main goal of Mono is to enable the last few months of Xamarin and Unity before their users fully migrate to .NET Core, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/, so in no way you should attempt to run your ASP.NET 4.x web apps on Mono, unless you are able to support yourself on every required bits. Seriously you should migrate to ASP.NET Core for that.

Comment: If that was an option, I'd already be there - our new and isolated stuff is all core stack but we have a significant legacy monolith where migration is a challenge. Production wise it all runs on Windows, but dev machines are mixed environments for what best suits any given solution. This is a "fun" exercise to see how far we can go getting the legacy stack running so I don't have to reboot every time I need to do an API endpoint tweak. If I can get as far as building and running unit tests that will be an achievement.